# Index Types not Inferring in Typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inference

I have a small code where TS drives me crazy...

```
type MyCustomType<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
  key: keyof T;
};

export const myFunction = <T extends Record<string, string>>(variable: MyCustomType<T>) => {
  const newVar: string = variable.key;
};
```

Typescript keeps complaining that **variable.key** can be **string | number | symbol** and can't be assign to **newVar**. But I typed my generic object as **Record<string, string>**.

So, why TS can't guess it's a string ?

How can I type these, without using **as**

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not infer `keyof T` to be `string` because it does not have to be a `string`. Your constraint merely states that every `string` key must have a `string` value. But `T` might also have `number` or `symbol` keys.

```
myFunction<Record<0, string>>({ key: 0 })
// no error, the constraint is fulfilled
```

So we should explicitly forbid `number` and `symbol` keys.

```
type MyCustomType<
  T extends Record<string, string> 
    & Record<number | symbol, never>
> = {
  key: keyof T & string;
};

export const myFunction = <
  T extends Record<string, string> 
    & Record<number | symbol, never>
>(variable: MyCustomType<T>) => {
  const newVar: string = variable.key;
  console.log(newVar)
};
```

This still does not silence the error. TypeScript is not able to deduct that `keyof T` is a `string`. After all, it could still have `number` properties of type `never` (which practically is not possible but you could still explicitly pass a type containing `never` values). But we can now *"safely"* intersect `keyof T` with `string`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCBXAzsA9gWwCrggHgCgoosoIAPYCAOwBNkoAlCAYzQCda9V2BLagOYAaKD34CAfFCLEoAMiasOXaogwAjCOygAfUSA1oANiOoQAblokEpAXigBvGQGsIIAFxRXINADMS8qLAfIIA3AQAvuEEFGAcwFBs1KhQGCAAYojULMC8aNRQ9oTEpBRUdAzMbJzcweIiYoJSMsQKVcp4qhpauvqGJlBmluzWEgAU5gCGfJPqRhCecEiomDiQeFgSAJSFUk7ESSlmAO4AatOejQKFUFMzcxAAdN7hB-nIxk9GaAJjJ%20fsLaRaIENKZbK5fJ4do1ABEk1hDTqTXGDi8bk88NhUAiQLBWRyeWo0KUNQADEiQpJUeiPFAyTitkA)